# Reading Excel with C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read an Excel file with C# and I keep getting this error: `oledbexception cannot update. database or object is read-only` on the line. Any ideas?

```
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        //file upload path

        string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        //Create connection string to Excel work book
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
        //Create Connection to Excel work book
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Coupon], [First Name], [Last Name] from [Sheet1$]",excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
        //Give your Destination table name
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "CPC_Coupons";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend the newer ACE provider instead of the old JetDB one. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Are you opposed to using Interop instead (http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/262228)?

Comment: Try using the Microsoft.Office.Interop library instead

Comment: If you are running on a x64 system the only solution is to use the Office 2010 Ace.OLEDB Provider.  Even if you are not on a x64 system you should be using the Ace.OLEDB Provider that comes with Vista/Windows 7 that is connected to Office 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following code if that might help in your scenario:

```
  public static class DatabaseManager
    {
        //set connection string for SQL Server Express Edition
        static string connString = @"Data Source=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DocumentStore;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";


        //method to save document to database
        public static bool SaveDocumentToDatabase(MemoryStream msDocument, DocumentType docType, string documentName)
        {
            //keep track of the save status 
            bool isSaved = false;

            //create database connection
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Settings.LogException(ex);
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to open database connection");
                isSaved = false;
            }

            string commandText = "INSERT INTO Documents (DocumentType, DocumentName, DocumentContent, CreateDate) VALUES('" + docType + "','" + documentName + "', @DocumentContent ,'" + DateTime.Now + "')";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("DocumentContent", msDocument.ToArray());
            try
            {
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Document saved successfully");
                isSaved = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to save the document to database");
                Settings.LogException(ex);
                isSaved = false;
            }

            //close database connect
            sqlConnection.Close();


            return isSaved;
        }

    public static bool LoadDocumentFromDataBase(DocumentType docType)
    {
         //keep track of the retrieve status 
        bool isRetrieved = false;


        //create database connection
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to open database connection");
            Settings.LogException(ex);
            isRetrieved = false;
        }


        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE DocumentType ='" + docType + "'";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, sqlConnection);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);

        DataTable dtDocuments = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtDocuments);
            Console.WriteLine("Document retrieved successfully");
            isRetrieved = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve documents from database");
            Settings.LogException(ex);
            isRetrieved = false;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to change connectionstring like this, from [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

as there is article in MS Support site for this [ADO.net with Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

```
 string FileName = GettheFileName; 
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+FileName+";Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

from MS support site [ADO.net with Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

> To work around this problem for read-only data, enable Import Mode by
>   using the setting "IMEX=1" in the Extended Properties section of the
>   connection string. This enforces the ImportMixedTypes=Text registry
>   setting.

PS : If you do not have column headings, you need to specify HDR=No in the connection string

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know what the user will have the file called. They will be uploading it through a web page. So the name could be different things.

Comment: @Justin checkupdated ans. you can pass a varible to that connectionstring, and use  it

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't give that error anymore, but now it gives a weird path and can't find it. The path starts with "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\" that it gives. BTW. I am using a FileUpload control and using this to get my path "string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;" Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: share your code. of fileupload. or give the path where your saving the excel file

Comment: come to chat room,will help there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7170/discussion-between-ravi-and-justin)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my method, works with sheets created in Excel 2007.

```
public static DataTable ReadExcel(string path)
{
    //create a DataTable to hold the query results
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            return null;

        //create the "database" connection string 
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        //create the database query
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" ;

        //create an OleDbDataAdapter to execute the query
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
        //fill the DataTable
        dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        dAdapter.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    return dTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to over simply...

Make sure that the doc is closed in Excel (Excel gets a read-only share lock on it - I think its been awhile)

Interop can give you issues if you are trying to use this in a server environment - COM permissions and such...

I might also suggest using a **using** block to make sure everything disposed after executing:

```
using(OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)) {
  //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Coupon]\t[First Name]\t[Last Name] from [Sheet1$]",excelConnection);
  excelConnection.Open();
...
  excelConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\janki.prashar\Desktop\k.xls";
    string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended     Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand ad = new OleDbCommand("select * from [SheetName$]", con);
    OleDbDataReader dr = ad.ExecuteReader();
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
```